# How to get line numbers instead of line offsets in symbolicated crash reports?

Tags: objective-c, symbolicatecrash

I have a question that's been bugging me for a while.  For our symbolicated crash reports, for internal frameworks that we have the source code for, symbolicated crash reports frequently have offsets instead of line numbers.  For instance, the symbolicated report has:

```
*AppName*   0x0025b0b2 -[*AppSpecificClass AppSpecificMessage*:] + 682
```

when we'd like to have:

```
*AppName*   0x001c444d __39-[*AppSpecificClass AppSpecificMessage*] (*AppSpecificClass*.m:145)
```

I have tried a bunch of different permutations of build settings but I cannot get this to work consistently (we do get line numbers for some parts of the crash).

Thanks for the help,
Rob

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that.  I am aware of how to symbolicate crashes and my reports get symbolicated (i'm not just staring at memory addresses).  My questions is pertaining to the product of the symbolicating process not having line numbers.

Comment: i think you can do it in preferences not sure though

Answer (score 0):

What tool you are using?

Works fine here via dwarfdump

```
7   MyApp                           0x0004e4d1 -[MyClassInstance myFunc] (in MyApp) 'MyModule.mm' line 100, column 9 with start address 0x000000000004e4a3
```